# C# Regex Expression is needed

Tags: c#

Problem:

I have a list of fields, List {"CustomerID", "Amount", "order id"}. Need to extract the values from below text

Sample Text 1:

CustomerID:    B377JWIWV10LEX

Amount: Rs.1500

order id : 604-1343456290402730
Reason:  Customer tried making a payment for 1500 via UPI

Sample Text 2:

CustomerID :  B377JWIWV10LEX

AmOunt: 1500

order id : 604-1343456290402730 424
Reason:  Customer tried making a payment for 1500 via UPI

Sample Text 3:

CustomerID # B377JWIWV10LEX

AmOunt: 1500

order id : 6041343456290402730424
Reason:  Customer tried making a payment for 1500 via UPI

Tried the below Regex:

"(?<="+ valueInList +"\s*(No|#|id|:|-|\s)*\s*(Rs.|Rs|Rs\s*.))(.*)(?!\n)*"

Not getting the exact value.

Regex tested in : https://regex101.com/r/xdK4St/1

Comment: After your regex runs, and lets say it does the job, what kind of variable type are you intending to use to hold the data?

Comment: I with put the values in a map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a regex for each field you want to extract. For example, for customer id we have `(CustomerID)\s*[:#]\s*(\w+)`. Here, `(\w+)` will match the actual id. Similar for the amount: `(amount)\s*:\s*(rs\.)?(\d+)` where `(\d+)` is the amount. Note that the regexes should be made case-insensitive.

Comment: no it would be dayamic.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment? What would be dynamic?

Comment: I will have a list of {id, amount, dates } etc . The values of the list will be changing. It can be {id, amount, reason} also